# Calling a C# function from inno setup

Tags: c#, inno-setup

I'm trying to call a C# function from Inno Setup, however I'm getting the error

> Internal error: extracttemporyfile the file "ClassLibrary1.dll" was not found`

I have placed the .dll file in the same folder as the inno setup script and even tried adding the .dll to the `[files]` section like this

```
[Files]
Source: "ClassLibrary1.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
```

However I still get the same error as above.

Here in my C# code including the namespace (this is just to test if the function can be called)

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public class ActivationClass
   {
      [DllExport("Activation", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static Boolean Activation([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string input)
      {
        if (input == "1a2b3c")
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the Inno Setup Script

```
[Code]
function Activation(key: WideString): Boolean;
external 'Activation@files:ClassLibrary1.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var status: Boolean;
begin
status := Activation('1a2b3c');
   case status of
   true: msgbox('true', mbInformation, MB_OK);
   false: msgbox('false',mbInformation, MB_OK);
   end;
Result := status; 
end;
```

Comment: unfortunately that's all its giving me, the code compiles, normally it wouldn't if it cant see the file I believe, so I'm a little confused as to why it wont access it

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Everything works just fine for me with your code. We need [mcve]. Make sure you copy paste *exact* code, as this looks like you have a typo somewhere. At least the error message was obviously typed by hand, not copied, as the literal error message is different.

Comment: What is exactly, how it looks? The exact error message would be `ExtractTemporaryFile: The file "ClassLibrary1.dll" was not found` + I do not understand what you mean by *"how are you storing the dll"*.

Comment: the code I have posted is exactly how it looks in my ides, how are you storing the file, i mean, how are you putting it to? in the same folder as the script?

Comment: Yes, otherwise `Source: "ClassLibrary1.dll"` would not work.

Comment: `DllExport` is not for COM.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yeah Ok, that's how i have it too, weird.

Comment: Can you compile a simple installer that shows the problem and upload it somewhere?

Comment: I just added the `[Files]` section back to see if it would make a difference again, at least now im getting a different error `cannot import dll: <utf8>ClassLibaray.dll` I changed my C# build to x86, however the error is the same as mentioned

Comment: Of course, you need the `[Files]` section entry. I assumed that you have it there. + You need the `x86` + `ClassLibaray.dll` - again that looks like a typo. - Anyway, you now have a completely different question, so it's time to edit your question and cleanup the comments.

Comment: yeah I thought by having 'Activation@files:ClassLibrary1.dll stdcall'; that it would call it automatically without having to add the dll to the file section.